# symfony2 leftjoin condition on right - losing data

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm-postgres

I have 3 entities

. "Ejuridique" has 1 relation "onetomany" with

. "Project"   has 1 relation "onetomany" with

. "Photo"

**When I do 1 query on "Ejuridique" and cascading left join on "Project" and after on "Photo", adding conditions on projects and photos, I lose all the "Ejuridiques" who do not have projects. But I would like to keep all the "Ejuridique" even if they do not have projects.**

I have tried all the solutions given for other questions similar with this one found on forums, but it still does not work.

**with querybuilder in my repository**

```
class EjuridiqueRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myFindAll()
        {
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->leftjoin('a.projets', 'pr' )
                ->leftjoin('pr.photos', 'ph' )
                ->where('pr.projetPosition = :position_pr')
                ->ANDwhere('ph.position = :position_ph')
                ->setParameters(array('position_pr'=> "1",'position_ph'=> "1"))
                ->addSelect('pr')
                ->addSelect('ph');

            return $qb->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
        }
}
```

**OR with DQL**

```
$dql = "SELECT e,pr,ph FROM chlwebsitesBundle:Ejuridique e LEFT JOIN e.projets pr  
LEFT JOIN pr.photos ph WHERE pr.projetPosition=1 AND ph.position=1";

$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
$ejuridiques = $query->getResult();
```

I lose data with both the 2 methods.

Thank you in advance for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that your `WHERE` clause has conditions for project and photo entities, so any entity where these relations are null will not be returned.

You need to put these conditions in your `LEFT JOIN` i.e.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
->leftjoin('a.projets', 'pr' \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'pr.projetPosition = :position_pr')
->leftjoin('pr.photos', 'ph', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'ph.position = :position_ph' )
->setParameters(array('position_pr'=> "1",'position_ph'=> "1"))
->addSelect('pr')
->addSelect('ph');
```